# set default image on model from s3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-models

For user profiles i have a default image on the model

`image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')`

I now have this image in the s3 bucket. How can I reference this image from the s3 bucket and not local

if I try and use the direct image path on the model `https://uploadfiles.s3.amazonaws.com/profile_pics/default.jpg` or the bucket path `'uploadfiles/profile_pics/default.jpg` i get the error `This backend doesn't support absolute paths`

I'm not sure how else I would reference the image I do have proper access to the buckets and uploading is working properly

**UPDATE:**

I corrected the `This backend doesn't support absolute paths` the offending code was `img = Image.open(self.image.path)` i corrected it with `img = Image.open(self.image.name)` still have a hard time getting the file in a location that the app is happy with

**UPDATE2:**

So inside my static folder i created a folder called `staticimages` with the default image `static\staticimages\default.jpg` I then run collectstatic and the files get uploaded to the s3 bucket. Now the issue here is when the files get uploaded to s3 they are not in a folder called static and the files are directly uploaded to the bucket. So the link to the file on the model no longer works because the `static` folder does not exists on the s3 bucket but it does locally this causes an error for the file not existing. How would it be possible to link the file then if the directory structure can never match from local to s3.

**Update3:**

I got it to work if i put the image in the root directory of the s3 bucket. Although this is not ideal and i would rather have it in a folder this will work for now

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to build absolute uri to the image the rest is just then bucket policy stuff on S3.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from django.utils.encoding import iri_to_uri

def build_absolute_uri(location):
    # type: (str) -> str
    host = Site.objects.get_current().domain
    protocol = "https" if settings.ENABLE_SSL else "http"
    current_uri = "%s://%s" % (protocol, host)
    location = urljoin(current_uri, location)
    return iri_to_uri(location)


@celery_app.task()
def send_expense_record(id):
    send_kwargs, ctx = get_email_context()
    expense = Expense.objects.get(pk=id)
    imagelink = build_absolute_uri(expense.image.url)
    ctx["imagelink"] = imagelink
    email = send_templated_mail(
     template_name="property/expense",
     recipient_list=settings.ADMINS,
     context=ctx,
        **send_kwargs,
    )

    return email
```

Comment: what is the get_email_context() mean here